# Проблема с кодировкой при парсинге сообщения твич

Tags: python

Есть переменная message в нее парсится сообщение и получается, что то по типу \xd0\xbf\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb5\xd1\x82
И как это можно перевести в нормальную строку?
ps: нужно чтобы именно переменная message потом станвоилась нормальной строкой с правильной кодировкой (сообщение берется с чата твича, если это как то делу поможет)

Comment: Можно посмотреть код?
Просто была похожая проблема, возможно смогу помочь))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если это имеет тип bites то можно просто применить метод decode

```
b'\xd0\xbf\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb5\xd1\x82'.decode('utf-8')
```

эта строка даст `"привет"`.

Если у вас строка с escape-последовательностью, т.е.:

```
 b = '\\xd0\\xbf\\xd1\\x80\\xd0\\xb8\\xd0\\xb2\\xd0\\xb5\\xd1\\x82'
```

то можно такой способ применить:

```
b.encode('latin1').decode('unicode-escape').encode('latin1').decode('utf-8')
```

вызовы encode нужны потому что они возвращают байты, у которых есть методы decode

Ну и последний случай, если у вас вдруг так задана переменная:

```
a = '\xd0\xbf\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb5\xd1\x82'
```

То декодировать её можно так:

```
a.encode('latin1').decode('utf-8')
```